# How to interpret Timelien for HighStock

Tags: json, date, time, highcharts

I am using the HighStock API of HighChart.

The demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Makes a timeline on the x-Axis.
But the data JSON data for the graph has the following keys:
E.g. for AAPL:

```
?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */
[
/* Dec 2008 */
[1229472000000,12.74],
[1229558400000,12.78],
[1229644800000,12.86],
[1229904000000,12.25],
[1229990400000,12.34],
[1230076800000,12.15],
[1230249600000,12.26],
[1230508800000,12.37],
[1230595200000,12.33],
[1230681600000,12.19],
```

How do all the `1229....` values relate to Date/Time?? I mean how does

```
1232582400000
```

relate to `22. January 2009`???

And I have data int he following format in Java:

```
2015-12-10 15:27
```

How should I use them in the HighChart API?

Comment: Reference:  http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric time stamps you see as "1232582400000" is the javascript time stamp. I believe it is UNIX epoch time in milliseconds (multiply epoch time by 1000). You can convert your human-readable time values into javascript time in any number of ways. The basic example if you have year, month, day, hour, and second would be to make your data series use [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
[Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute), yValue]
```

> "Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for
>   describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that
>   have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC),
>   Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds."

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))